# Losing object reference from array after search in the array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, object

hello there people of stackoverflow ,

my problem is I lose one of my states in array E (the one that has isfinal set to true) it goes null 
I don't see how i'm dropping the reference to the object I even made a new State in the method i'm a beginner in Java coming from C any help is appreciated i'll include pictures of the state of variables when debugging .

[Before the FindFinalStates Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z66dO.png) and
[After the FindFinalStates Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZYUq.png)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class State {
private final int ID;
private final boolean isFinal;

public State(int iD, boolean isFinal) {
    ID = iD;
    this.isFinal = isFinal;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public boolean isFinal() {
    return isFinal;
}

public static State[] FindFinalStates(State[] E) {
    List<State> F = new ArrayList<State>();

    for (int i = 0; i < E.length; i++) {
        if (E[i].isFinal()) {
            F.add(new State(E[i].getID(), true));

        }


    }
    return F.toArray(E);

}
```

}

and in my main class I have

```
State[] E = new State[3];
    E[0]= new State(0,false);
    E[1]= new State(1,true);
    E[2]= new State(2,false);
    State[] F = State.FindFinalStates(E);
```

any other tips on the style whatsoever is also appreciated thank you very much for your time

Comment: A style tip is that by convention variable and method names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Review what List.toArray does.  You are clobbering E.

Comment: Change your return statement to return F.toArray(new State[F.size()]);

Comment: Thank you everyone that worked